# Redirecionamento ao clicar em data list

Tags: html

Alguém pode me ajudar? (a outra pergunta tava errada)

Como faço para redirecionar ao clicar na opção desejada?

como no site: [www.outcenter.com.br](http://www.outcenter.com.br)

Quando a pessoa começa a digita. Já aparece a sugestão. Porém não é redirecionado para lugar nenhum. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Selecione sua cidade para continuar:

---

```
<option value ="Sta. Cruz Cabralia"></option>
<option value ="Coroa Vermelha"></option>
<option value ="Trancoso"></option>
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Redirecionamento ao clicar em opção de datalist](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/485592/redirecionamento-ao-clicar-em-op%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-datalist)

Comment: Não é preciso repetir a pergunta. Volte na pergunta original e edite a mesma.

Comment: Você pode usar o método change(); do jQuery